# How to align two input fields of two different forms inline, when div is shown?

Tags: html, css

I have two forms in jsp.

I want the input fields in both the forms to be center aligned and in single line.

I also hide a div which is shown when the input field studentName is clicked. If input field regNo is clicked, the div needs to be hidden. By default the div needs to be hidden

Now when I enter something in input field name, the alignment of two input fields changes badly

jsp code

```
<div id="mycontainer">  
    <form method="get" action="number" id="number">
    <!--    <div id="regNoErrorMsgNumber">Only numbers are allowed</div> -->
            <div style="text-align: center;" >
                    <!-- //TODO: Only number, no spaces, no special symbol and 12 digit check-->                

                             <input  width="20" type="text" data-validation="numbers" id="regNo" name="regNo" size="30" maxLength="50" placeholder="Enter Register Number"> <b>OR</b>       

            </div>

    </form>           

    <form method="post" action="name" id="name">                 
                <input  type="text" id="studentName" name="studentName" size="30" maxLength="50" placeholder="Enter Student Name" > 


            <c:set var="salary" scope="session" value="${param.studentName}"/>

        <div id="dropDown" style="display:none">
            <div id="studentNameError">
                <c:if test="${searchBy.hasError}">
                    <c:out
                        value="There are more than 100 results by this name. We suggest you to filter by College Name and/or Department Name" />
                </c:if>
                <br />
            </div>

            <div>
                <b>Filter students by College :</b> <select id="byCollege" name="byCollege">
                    <c:forEach items="${uniqueCollList}" var="uniqueCollList">
                        <option value="${uniqueCollList}">${uniqueCollList}</option>
                    </c:forEach>
                </select>
            </div>
            <br />

            <div>
                <b>Filter students by Department :</b> <select id="byDept" name="byDept">
                    <c:forEach items="${uniqueDeptList}" var="uniqueDeptList">
                        <option value="${uniqueDeptList}">${uniqueDeptList}</option>
                    </c:forEach>
                </select>
            </div>
            <br />
        </div>          
    </form>                 
</div>
```

css code

```
#mycontainer, h1, h3 {
            text-align:center;
        }
        form{
            display:inline-block;
        }
```

JS code

```
$('#dropDown').hide();
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#inputFields').click(function(event){
            if (document.getElementById('regNo').value !=""){           

                $("#number").submit();

            }else if(document.getElementById('studentName').value !=""){
                $("#name").submit();
            }
        });
    });    
    $(document).ready(function(){
          $('#regNo').click(function(event){              
             $('#studentName').val(''); 
             $('#dropDown').hide();
          });
          $('#studentName').click(function(event){            
             $('#regNo').val(''); 
             $('#dropDown').show();
          });

    });
```

Here is the code http://jsfiddle.net/7zwvcs4n/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add vertical-align:top; to the css for the form

```
    #mycontainer, h1, h3 {
        text-align:center;
    }
    form{
        vertical-align:top;
        display:inline-block;
        max-width: 49%;
        text-align:left;
    }
```

I updated your fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/7zwvcs4n/2/

Comment: Nope. Still not working. This is how it shows  http://postimg.org/image/bp64exwvp/

Comment: Your screen is tooo small :)

you will need another  max-width: 49%; (or, if you want the right column to be wider, use two different width)

I edited my answer.

Comment: Wow. It is working. http://postimg.org/image/nbm53622r/  But how can I bring the Filter by students to start right below Enter Register number input field.

Comment: I am unsure how your code looks now, but in this fiddle, it works. I had to add another text-align:left
http://jsfiddle.net/7zwvcs4n/2/

Comment: Is it possible to bring the two filter drop down to start from below the Enter Register number, input field.

Comment: with a float:left instead of display:inline-block http://jsfiddle.net/7zwvcs4n/6/